# Erro no Joomla: Joomla\Filesystem\File::delete: Failed deleting inaccessible file

Tags: php, joomla

A alguns dias venho enfrentando um problema atípico com o Joomla na versão 3.9.5. Fiz a migração do site de um servidor Linux para outro e ao tentar realizar alguns ajustes nas configurações globais do Joomla o seguinte erro é retornado após clicar no botão Salvar:

> Joomla\Filesystem\File::delete: Failed deleting inaccessible file bea6467846ac52096cea865ca370f3c6

Identifiquei também que o mesmo erro ocorre ao tentar instalar um modulo qualquer. Nas pesquisas que realizei algumas pessoas informaram que poderia ser problema de permissão e que talvez o problema seja com o processo de migração, enfim, nada que consegui recolher de material até o momento resolveu o problema. Para tirar a dúvida de que poderia ser algo com a aplicação, fiz a instalação de um Joomla puro na versão 3.9.5 no mesmo ambiente do site que apresenta o erro e o problema também acontece nessa instalação. Uma observação é que no ambiente anterior esse erro não era apresentado e tenho também praticamente a mesma aplicação rodando localmente no EasyPHP com PHP 7.1 e tudo funciona como deveria.

**Segue um pouco do setup:** Joomla 3.9.5 - PHP 7.2.16 - Servidor Linux - Painel Cpanel - Diretorios com permissão 755 e arquivos com 644. Para visualizar tanto a aplicação que migrei quanto o Joomla que instalei depois, utilizo a URL temporária disponível no painel pois não apontei o DNS ainda.

Comment: Após a publicação dessa duvida, realizei mais testes e consegui notar uma coisa, no método estático delete que se encontra em libraries/src/Filesystem/File.php o sistema tenta fazer a substituição de arquivos da forma casual (que eu não sei como funciona), quando isso não é possível ele tenta fazer através do FTP e para que ele possa ter acesso é necessário nas configurações do Joomla habilitar o modo FTP e preencher os dados de acesso, dessa maneira o sistema terá a permissão necessária. Como através do painel não era possível salvar, alterei direto no configuration.php.

Comment: Alguém teria alguma ideia do que pode estar causando esse problema de permissão?